# How to reorder multiple df in a list

Tags: r

I have a list of df. I would like to sort each df in `lst` using  the info from `Order`. I try to use `map` or `map2` to do this. however my codes doesn't work. Any suggestion?

I would like to know how to achive this goal using `map`, or `lapply` if that is doable. Thanks.

```
## Sample list
lst1<- list(Test = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-05-202", "101-06-203", 
"102-10-401", "101-11-402", "105-12-403", "101-13-501", "101-14-502", 
"101-15-503", "101-01-101", "101-05-202", "101-06-203", "101-11-402", 
"101-13-501", "101-14-502", "101-15-503", "101-01-101", "101-05-202", 
"101-06-203", "101-11-402", "101-13-501", "101-14-502", "101-15-503", 
"101-01-101", "101-05-202", "101-06-203", "101-11-402", "101-13-501", 
"101-14-502", "101-15-503", "101-05-202", "101-06-203", "101-11-402", 
"101-13-501", "101-14-502", "101-15-503", "101-06-203", "101-11-402", 
"101-13-501", "101-14-502", "101-15-503", "101-11-402", "101-13-501", 
"101-14-502", "101-15-503", "101-06-203", "101-11-402", "101-14-502", 
"101-06-203", "101-14-502", "101-06-203", "101-06-203", "101-06-203", 
"101-06-203", "101-06-203", "101-06-203"), Test = c("ELA", 
"ELA", "ART", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA, PE", "ELA", 
"ELA", "ELA", "ELA, MATH", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA,PE", "ELA", "ELA", 
"ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "PE", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", 
"ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA,MATH", "ELA", "ELA", 
"ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", 
"ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", 
"ELA,PE", "ELA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -55L
)), Comments = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", "101-02-102", 
"106-03-103", "101-05-202", "103-04-201", "103-09-303", "105-12-403"
), COMYN = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L)), Enroll = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", "101-02-102", 
"106-03-103", "101-05-202", "103-04-201", "101-06-203", "102-07-301", 
"105-08-302", "103-09-303", "102-10-401", "101-11-402", "105-12-403"
), EDT = c("09/03/2020", "09/11/2020", "10/08/2020", "12/08/2020", 
"12/09/2020", "12/23/2020", "02/02/2021", "02/17/2021", "03/10/2021", 
"04/19/2021", "04/28/2021", "06/03/2021")), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), spec = structure(list(cols = list(SubjectID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Group = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Site = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), SubjectStatus = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Visit = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Form = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), FormEntryDate = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
"collector")), ICDT = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), ICDT_CODED = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
"collector")), ICPVDATE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), ICPVDATE_CODED = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Informed_C_CREATE_DTM = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Informed_C_LAST_UPD_DTM = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), SubjectVisitFormID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec")))

## Order file
Order<-structure(list(File = c("Test", "Comments", "Enroll"), Order = c("SubjectID", 
"SubjectID", "SubjectID, mdy(EDT)")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

## Order lst with Order
lst[Order$File] <- map2(lst[Order$File], Order$Order, ~ .x %>% 
                          arrange(paste(.y)))
```

Comment: I try to sort each df. for `lst["Enroll"]` , i would like to get `lst[{"Enroll"]] <-lst[{"Enroll"]]  %>% arrange(SubjectID, mdy(EDT))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may need to `parse` the expression

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
lst1[Order$File] <- map2(lst1[Order$File], Order$Order,
      ~ .x %>%
        arrange(!!! rlang::parse_exprs(str_replace(.y, ",", ";"))))
```

Comment: Why we need  `!!!` ? why we need to change `,` to `;`?

Comment: @Stataq According to `?parse_expr` - `parse_expr() returns one expression. If the text contains more than one expression (separated by semicolons or new lines),`, which parse to `R expressions` and then `!!!` does the evaluation `It is sometimes useful to force early evaluation of part of an expression before it gets fully evaluated. The tidy eval framework provides several forcing operators for different use cases. ... The big-bang operator !!! forces-splice a list of objects. The elements of the list are spliced in place, meaning that they each become one single argument.`

Comment: @Stataq the idea is to separate the expressions as new expressions when there are multiple expressions in a single line;  Just like we do `x <- 5; y <- 10` in a single line instead of writing in different lines

Comment: I tried the codes, however for `Enroll`, it is not sorted by `EDT`. Not sure why.

Comment: @Stataq The code gives the same output as `tmp1 <- lst1[[3]] %>% arrange(SubjectID, mdy(EDT)); tmp2 <- lst1[[3]] %>% arrange(!!! rlang::parse_exprs(str_replace(Order$Order[3], ",", ";")));
> identical(tmp1, tmp2)
[1] TRUE`

Comment: @Stataq I would check the sorting or SubjectID because it is first sorted by SubjectID which is not a numeric vector

Comment: I see `SUbjectID` is chr. Will that affect the arrange results?

Comment: @Stataq yes.  It is first sorted by SubjectID and then by date column.  If you do the reverse, will understand it i.e. `lst1[[3]] %>% arrange(mdy(EDT), SubjectID)`

Comment: Silly me. I forgot about subjectID when I check EDT.  Thanks a bunch!